# Authorized.net is not working in magento2.3.2

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, magento2.3.2, sandbox-mode

I setup configuration in the Test site. The **Sandbox mode credential** set now.

https://prnt.sc/ogarkh

when I pay using an authorized payment method it gives an error:

> Root element is missing.
>
> https://prnt.sc/ogaqcy

anyone have a solution please share it.